EF Core Entity OwnsOne Value Object Change Tracking Problem
Edit 1: Github Issue link : https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/33981
We have an entity named Customer which has a Name Property that is a value Object. I'm sharing the entity value object and their relations and configuration below.
My question is: When I started tracking a customer entity and change the value object property is not considered as modified. I have to force it by calling
(_customersDbContext.Set<BoilerPlate.SampleAPI.Core.Customer>()
.Entry(customer).Member("Name") as ReferenceEntry).TargetEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;

However its not solving my problem becase I need original values of Name field when I changed Name property OriginalValues and CurrentValues setted same values. I want to get original values as getting when I select with traccking records.
Let me sampling:
Step 1 (Getting customer Entity)
var customer= await _customersDbContext.Set<BoilerPlate.SampleAPI.Core.Customer>()
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 41)`

Name property has firstname 1: lastname: 1 values.
Step 2 (Updating Name which is value object property)

customer.Update(
Gender.From(command.GenderId == null ? customer.Gender.Id : command.GenderId.Value),
Name.Of("2", "2"));


Step 3 (Cheking the original values)
var xxxx = (_customersDbContext.Set<BoilerPlate.SampleAPI.Core.Customer>().Entry(customer)
.Member("Name") as ReferenceEntry).TargetEntry.OriginalValues;

Firstname and Lastname orginal values are 2 not 1.
How to avoid this problem, please help me thanks in advance
Customer.cs
public class Customer : Aggregate,
{
private Name _name;

public Name Name => _name;
}

Name.cs
public class Name : ValueObject
 {
     private string _firstName;
     public string FirstName => _firstName;

     private string _lastName;
     public string LastName => _lastName;

     private string _fullName;
     public string FullName => _fullName;

     private Name() { }

     public static Name Of(
         [NotNull] string firstName,
         [NotNull] string lastName)
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName) || firstName.Length is > 100 or < 2)
             throw new InvalidNameException(firstName);

         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName) || lastName.Length is > 100 or < 2)
             throw new InvalidNameException(lastName);

         firstName = RemoveInlineSpaces(firstName);
         lastName = RemoveInlineSpaces(lastName);

         static string RemoveInlineSpaces(string text)
         {
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                 return Regex.Replace(text.Trim(), @" +", " ");
             return null;
         }

         Name customerName = new()
         {
             _firstName = firstName,
             _lastName = lastName,
         };

         customerName.SetFullName();

         return customerName;
     }

     private void SetFullName()
     {
         _fullName = $"{_firstName} {_lastName}";
     }

     protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
     {
         yield return _firstName;
         yield return _lastName;
     }
 }

Entity Type Configuration .cs for Customer:
builder.OwnsOne(
x => x.Name,
a =>
{
a.Property(p => p.FirstName)
.HasColumnName(nameof(Customer.Name.FirstName).Underscore())
.IsRequired()
.HasField("_firstName")
.HasMaxLength(EfConstants.Lenght.Long);

    a.Property(p => p.LastName)
        .HasColumnName(nameof(Customer.Name.LastName).Underscore())
        .IsRequired()
        .HasField("_lastName")
        .HasMaxLength(EfConstants.Lenght.Long);

    a.Property(p => p.FullName)
        .HasColumnName(nameof(Customer.Name.FullName).Underscore())
        .IsRequired()
        .HasField("_fullName")
        .HasMaxLength(EfConstants.Lenght.ExtraLong);
});


The issue with EF Core not tracking changes to the Name value object in your Customer entity arises because EF Core doesn't automatically detect changes within value objects. To resolve this, you need to manually notify EF Core of these changes by explicitly marking the properties of the Name value object as modified when you update them. This can be achieved by implementing a method to compare the old and new values of the Name object and setting the modified state for its properties.

"implementing a method to compare the old and new values of the Name object and setting the modified state for its properties." This is the exact problem. As I mentioned that I can not get the original values from Name Object its setted with currentValues by ef core. If I move the code from .net 7 and ef core .7 to ef 8 then use the code line below context.Set()
.Entry(customer).ComplexProperty(p => p.Name).Property(p => p.FirstName).OriginalValue; I can get the original values but I need them in EF CORE version 7.x.x
